Is union of two convergent sequences is a convergent sequence?
Fix a > 1. Take $x_1 >\sqrt{a}$ and define $x_{n+1} = \frac{a+x_n}{1+x_n}$ for all n $\geq 1$. Show that:
$\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = \sqrt{a}$
I have proved that $x_{2n-1}$ is decreasing and bounded below by $\sqrt{a}$ and $x_{2n}$ is increasing and bound above by $\sqrt{a}$.
Both sequence $x_{2n-1}$ and $x_{2n}$ are convergent can I say that $x_n$ is convergent ?

If you show that both $x_{2n-1}$ and $x_{2n}$ converge to $\sqrt{a}$, then yes.

I have a problem in proving that

Can you show $x_{2n-1} - \sqrt{a} < \sqrt{a} - x_{2n} < x_{2n+1} - \sqrt{a}$?
